# yum update doesn't have any update?

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel5

Recently, I clean up the yum cache, then I found that I don't have any update when I do yum update.
I am not sure whether there is actually no update or something is wrong.

```
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
```

`yum update`

> ```
> Loaded plugins: replace, rhnplugin, security
> This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
> Excluding Packages from Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)
> Finished
> Skipping security plugin, no data
> Setting up Update Process
> No Packages marked for Update
> ```

`yum repolist all`

> ```
> ...
> epel, Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64, enabled: 6,781   
> epel-debuginfo, Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64 - Debug, disabled
> rhel-x86_64-server-5, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64), enabled: 16,487+311
> ...
> ```

Last a few lines of yum.log

> ```
> Jul 01 14:57:09 Updated: openssl-perl-0.9.8e-36.el5_11.x86_64
> Jul 01 14:57:10 Updated: openssl-0.9.8e-36.el5_11.i686
> Jul 01 14:57:12 Updated: openssl-devel-0.9.8e-36.el5_11.i386
> Jul 10 09:15:31 Updated: dhcpv6-client-1.0.10-22.el5_11.x86_64
> ```

Under /etc/yum.repos.d **(I don't see rhel-x86_64-server-5 here?)**

```
ius-archive.repo
ius-dev.repo
ius.repo
ius-testing.repo
rhel-debuginfo.repo
rpmforge.repo
pgdg-92-redhat.repo
kbs-el5-rb187.repo
mirrors-rpmforge
mirrors-rpmforge-extras
mirrors-rpmforge-testing
epel.repo
varnish.repo
epel-testing.repo
```

Answer (score 2):

The line "*This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.*" in your yum output is a notification from the yum rhnplugin, that the system is registered with your local Satellite server of RHN Classic.

Software channels belonging to your RHN classic or Satellite subscription don't appear as repo files in /etc/yum.repos.d but are managed from the satellite server through your system ID and the rhnplugin.

Have you considered the thought that your system is simply [completely up to date for RHEL 5](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/rhel-server-errata.html)?

Because those recently installed OpenSSL packages match [RSA-2015:1197](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-1197.html) and the dhcp client version [RHBA-2015:1212](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2015-1212.html), which are momentarily some of the most recent errata.

Comment: https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/rhel-server-errata.html is very helpful. I think it is update to date.